# SSIS Package Date format

Tags: sql-server, azure, datetime, ssis, flat-file

I have a data factory in Azure that has a pipeline to execute an SSIS package. An extract script is included in this package that will convert a date value from `2019-01-13 00:00:00` to `2019-01-13`. After this, a logic app picks up the extract.txt file and sends it to sftp to drop into a folder.

As you can see from my extract script in SSMS converting a varchar data type to date (I receive date in Unix), for Arrival date the following value is given.

*Script*

[image: Script]

*Data viewer*

[image: Date Value]

However when I open my extract.txt file, the date shows as: `2019-01-13 00:00:00.0000000`

Can anyone tell me why they think this may be happening? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When you map a date column to flat file it will include time even if it doesn't appear in data viewer or ssms.**

## SSIS solution

Instead of using `dateadd()` in the source, leave the column as it is, in SSIS use a derived column with the following expression:

```
LEFT((DT_WSTR,50)DATEADD("s", [start], (DT_DATE)"1970-01-01",10)
```

*Output*

> 2019-01-13

Based on the [Cast (SSIS Expression) official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/cast-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017):

> When a string is cast to a DT_DATE, or vice versa, the locale of the transformation is used. However, the date is in the ISO format of YYYY-MM-DD, regardless of whether the locale preference uses the ISO format.

## SQL Server solution

Use the following SQL command:

```
select convert(varchar(10), dateadd(S, [start], '1970-01-01'),120)
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry for only getting back to this now, but I have been out of office. This worked correctly, I tried the SQL Server Solution and it gave me the format of the date I was looking for. Thanks very much!